# Issue with printing in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have one href link which prints my order details. Now on clicking this in firefox or chrome, order details are getting printed but the same is not happening in IE8.

Though in IE8, order details are getting printed but at the same time it reloads so my page goes to basket page as the current session has no pending orders to complete.

Actually one js file is there which checks the valid session but this js is not placed within the href but in the page, so I think in ie8 the page refreshes while I click the print href and this is causing the page to go basket page.

Please suggest how to get rid of this in IE8....

Comment: It sounds to me like you've got a rouge request that's pointing to an invalid URL - Firefox and Chrome will just ignore it but IE will post back to the most relative URL that can be found. Generally this happens when there is an image, JavaScript, or CSS request that's invalid.

Comment: Did you try to have your link `return false;` on the on the `onclick` event to stop the postback?

Comment: So, what will be the solution?